# how to add nothing values to a target list if the source list has empty values

Tags: vb.net

List x has values (nothing, nothing, nothing)

```
y = x.select(function(x) x).Take(2).ToList()
```

Here I want y(nothing,nothing) and count = 2.

But this gives a count of 0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  You'll have trouble with a list called x and a parameter called x too.

```
    Dim x = {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing}
    Dim y = x.Take(2).ToList()
    If y.Count <> 2 Then Throw New Exception("Failed")
```

Comment: Sorry.. I do not take the parameter x.. It was just an example.. sorry.. for some reason it doesn't work. I'm trying out this code in vb.net

Comment: Yep, that code works in vb.net. The only thing I can see that could be an issue is if you have another extension method declared for Take which has an error. I've modified my code as well as the select wasnt needed. If you create a new project and run this code you should see it works fine.